# How to Access data from one table to another new table dynamically in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a Table(customer) in my MySQL Database. In customer Table , I Have Some columns such as customerid, name, contactno, area, monthlyrent, address." Now I want to create a another new Table(payment) where I will have some column such as "customerid,name,contactno,area,monthlyrent,month,year,advance,pay,RunningDue,previousDue,TotalDue" So I want to access in "customer" Table for These column such as customerid,name,contactno,area,monthlyrent" . I mean in my "payment" Table, These customerid,name,contactno,area,monthlyrent" will be same to same as  "customer" Table. And if In my customer table a new information/row added then that information/row will be added automatically/dynamically into my "payment" Table. If Any information/row updated in customer table that updated information/row will show in payment Table. In summery, In customer Table's, new/upadted information each and everything will show in my payment Table.

```
INSERT INTO payment (customerid, name, contactno, area, monthlyrent)
SELECT customerid, name, contactno, area, monthlyrent
FROM customer;
```

I was try this SQL. but When I Add New customer or updated a customer's information that was not showing dynamically in my payment Table.

Comment: looks like you need triggers - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html , read,try, come back if you have problems

Comment: No, you do not want to automatically update these data in two different tables - this is what relationships and joins are for! In real life, payments / invoices tables often have a copy of the customer details as they were when the payment was made or the invoice issued due to legal requirements. But these details are not kept in sync with the master data.

Comment: @P.Salmon I read the Document. But I am Confused. Can You Please Explain. How To Solve That Problem. I want to learn that new things properly.